# Understanding tiles folder and file names

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, tiles

I have hard times finding the meaning of tiles names and folders. I don't think it's related to QGIS (it seems to be a standard thing) but when I export my map into a tile set the content is split into several folders.

[image]

The top folder is the zoom level. But inside I find a set of folders with numbers as names, and inside them a set of tiles with numbers as name. I understand the logic, folder is a "column" and every file is a new "row" of the column.

I imagine that these numbers define some coordinates in a way. But I can't find the logic behind it. For example here is the meta data exported by QGIS alongside the tiles :

```
"METADATA": {
 "map.coverage.center.longitude": 2.3287153244018484, 
 "map.coverage.bottomRight.latitude": 48.83833969137705, 
 "map.shortAttribution": "", 
 "map.type": "overlay", 
 "map.coverage.bottomRight.longitude": 2.343606948852528, 
 "map.tileFormat": "png", 
 "map.maxZoom": 18, 
 "map.coverage.topLeft.latitude": 48.85906816414893, 
 "map.coverage.center.latitude": 48.84870392776299, 
 "map.shortName": "nc", 
 "map.coverage.topLeft.longitude": 2.3138236999511683, 
 "map.longAttribution": "", 
 "map.minZoom": 16, 
 "map.longDescription": "", 
 "map.tileSideLength": 512
}
```

Is there a relation possible between the lat / long coordinates and folder / file names?